# Django execute class in script

Tags: python, django, cron

I have problem with executing script in Django application. This script must serve for job in crontab. So ill provide example of my script:

Specification:
Python:3.5.x
Django:1.10.5

## my_script.py

```
class SayHello(object):

    def print_args(self, arg1, arg2):
        print (arg1, arg2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo = SayHello()
    foo.print_args(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

But the main problem is when i want to include models in this script i got error: **ImportError: No module named "app"**

Folder structure:

say_hello (main folder)

-> **init**.py

-> my_script.py

How to run script but don't get errors from import statement into this script. Any advice would be great.

Comment: It's been a while since I used Django but I know it does a whole lot of bootstrapping in order to do all it's magic with models and the like.  The Django command line tool does allow you to create management commands which sounds like it could be appropriate for your use case: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You script must be in the folder management/commands/ of the app.

Script example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# example.py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print "Hello word!!"
```

To run the script:

```
./manage.py example
```

Here you have the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/